# How to implement Underscore's find array function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to implement the Underscore.js function [`_.find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find). I don't understand why my code below returns `undefined` for:

```
find([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num) {
  return num % 2 == 0;
});
```

Here is my attempt at the solution:

```
function find(arr,callback) {
  each(arr,item=>{
    if (callback(item)) {
      return item;
    };
  });
}
function each(arr,callback) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      callback(arr[i]);
    };
  } else{
    for(let key in arr) {
      callback(arr[key]);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
each(arr, item => {
    if (callback(item)) {
        return item;
    }
});
```

You're returning inside the inner function started with `item => {`. It doesn't short circuit the outer function. `return` only stops the function execution of the function you return from.

An `each` loop is not supposed to return anything, and an `each` loop is not supposed to short circuit and should run for every element in the collection. You shouldn't use `each` for a search function. I don't know how underscore's source does it, but a simple `for` loop here will allow you to return once something is found.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy Ray. Very helpful.